# How to interpret binary log output from Podman REST API?

Tags: rest, logging, containers, podman

When [reading logs from the Podman REST API](https://docs.podman.io/en/latest/_static/api.html?version=v4.3#tag/containers/operation/ContainerLogsLibpod), the output is obviously binary.

I realized that each log entry has a 8 byte long prefix. Something like this:

```
01 00 00 00 00 00 00 45 [... 69 bytes long log message ...]
01 00 00 00 00 00 00 33 [... 51 bytes long log message ...]
02 00 00 00 00 00 00 40 [... 64 bytes long log message ...]
```

So far I could not find any useful documentation on that. However, I think this prefix contains at least the stream, where the log message was coming from (stdout probably being `01`, stderr probably being `02`) and the length of the message. But I'm not sure what is exactly encoded into these 8 bytes and how. And I don't want to guess.

Is there any official specification somewhere or even some ready-to-use libraries to parse that binary content in some way?